# nodejs mongodb , getting no result from db

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Issue with working on data from MongoDb

**Connecting to MongoDb successfully** ,

but on find command , it should return an empty collection , yet nothing is returned.

what could be the issue , or how it could be monitored by some error messaging.

Thanks.

Project dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"epxress": "0.0.1-security",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"nodemon": "^2.0.2"
```

}

mongoose.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/ListsDB', { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then( ()=> {
    console.log("Connected to MongoDbB successfully ");
}).catch( (e) => {
    console.log("Error while attempting to connect to MongoDB");
    console.log(e);
});

mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true);
mongoose.set('useFindAndModify', false);

module.exports = {
    mongoose
};
```

list.model.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const ListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   title: {
       type: String,
       required: true,
       minlength: 1,
       trim: true
   }
})

const List = mongoose.model('List', ListSchema);

module.exports = { List }
```

app.js **Not Working**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const { List, Task } = require('./db/models');

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    next()
  })

app.get('/lists', (req,res) => {
    // We want to return an array of all the lists in the database
    List.find({}).then( (err, lists)=> {
        res.send(lists)
    })
})

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3000");
})
```

Comment: Did you mean `res.json(lists)`?

Comment: no, i think res.send(lists) is correct.

Comment: Have you imported the list in app.js ? 
Have you checked your console errors ?

Comment: @Shl can you please check ?

Comment: @Juhil Somaiya yes it is , also the err not returning anything,  is suspect its mongo issue , but dont know how to monitor it.

Comment: Isn't there any error in browser console ? or terminal ?

Comment: Can you please do, console.log(typeof(lists)) in your .then() function

Comment: using postman for testing ,no error is catched.

Comment: it is not reaching the then() , the promise is not returned when debugging

Comment: if you want to cross check, make the get function async and use async await instead promise and check what value you get, else it should be from localdb installation

Comment: app.get('/lists', async(req, res) => {
const result = await List.find({});
console.log(result)
})


replace your get function with this code and check

Comment: Check your mongodb by 

1: sudo systemctl status mongodb
2: mongo --eval 'db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 })'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing multiple argument in then block. Then is only accept single argument that is mark as success data. If you want to show errors also you have to pass in error argument in catch block.

Try This code :

```
    const express = require('express');
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    const List = require('./listModel');
    const mongoConnection = require('./mongoose');
    const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json({
    limit: '20mb',
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.get('/lists', (req,res) => {
     List.find().then( lists => {
                res.send(lists)
          }).catch(err =>
                res.send(err)
          );
 });

app.listen(3100, () => {
    console.log("Server is listening on port 3100");
})
```

Comment: I have tried out your code which is working fine with this solution.

Comment: There might be issue with his local mongodb @HardikPatel

Comment: it seem like it is a mongo issue indeed , any ideas how to verify/find issue

Comment: first of all make sure that you have mongoDB installed on your system as well as if installed then check that it is connected to your application.

Comment: i think you have not connected your mongoDB in your app.
add following line in your app.js file
const mongo = require('path to mongoconnection file');

Comment: verified all this, mongod is running from terminal , so looks fine.

Comment: yes but you have to establish your connection in your application, too. you have to import the connection file in your app.js file.

Comment: I have edit my answer. try this out and import the file according to your directory structure. hope this works for you.

Comment: eventually it worked,  require the mongoose was the missing part + reset port + restarting mongod service , Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this syntax

```
   app.get('/lists', (req,res) => {
     List.find({}).then( lists => {
        res.send(lists)
     }).catch(err =>
        console.log(err)
     );
   })
```

Comment: Are you seeing List imported in app.js ?
How it will get List ?

Comment: @JuhilSomaiya yes.